# Conditonal Density Function

Tags: probability, density-function

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)= \begin{cases}
   (x-y)   & 0 \lt x \lt 1, & -1 \lt y \lt 0 \\
   0       & \text{elsewhere}
  \end{cases}$$

How can I find  the conditional density function $Y$
$$f_Y(y | X \le0)$$

Comment: Since apparently $f_{X,Y}(x,y) =0$ for $x \le 0$, this may not be a meaningful question

Comment: Yes I know. Actually that is why I asked. What do we say about it? Do we say "The conditional density does not exist"?

Answer (score 3):

The conditional density for $f_Y$ conditioned on $X < 0$ is not well defined because the event $X<0$ can never happen.